# Lumped model not applying to PCBs

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, voltage-measurement, kirchhoffs-laws

Recently I have heard that KCL and KVL do not fully apply when performing electrical measurement on PCB traces. It was implied that PCBs are not completely lumped circuits - that is, we cannot assume the speed of light to be infinite while dealing with them at an appropriate precision. What could that mean?

Comment: And where did you hear that?

Answer (score 0):

It means you have to worry about transmission lines effects such as ringing, propagation delays, and reflections for RF and high speed digital circuits. It also means you have to worry about leakage currents for high impedance circuits, and interplane and parasitic capacitances for circuits dependent on very small values of capacitance.

You also have to worry about these effects when measuring said circuit since probes introduce elements to the circuit that are not there during normal operation and thus will affects its operation.

Nothing in real life is ever a lumped circuit though so if you keep digging in measurement you'll probably reach a point when the model breaks down.